# How to get recent games list of gamertag on Xbox live one in PHP

Tags: php, json, xbox

I used this link

```
https://www.xboxleaders.com/api/profile.json?gamertag=dwalsh83
```

dwalsh83 is a gamertag. The data of the gamertag returns successfully but doesn't with this one: michalmorganvgl

Comment: It clearly says "Player not found"

Comment: Yea, seems like the website you are calling doesn't know this username

Comment: @LPK no this username is exist and i am getting data at this site http://xboxliveapi.freezemc.com/gamertag/michalmorganvgl/

Comment: You are making a request to 2 different sites...

Comment: @LPK please suggest me the correct way because I want the game list of Xbox users.if you can provide me any official link for this it will be the best for me.

Comment: Since your accessing inofficial APIs there is no clear correct way. I guess you just have to live with that. Maybe find out how the APIs get their data and do it that way

Comment: @LPK I tried but did not find any official link please provide me if you have.

Comment: I guess there is no official API for such things. Have you notied this message at xboxleaders? "XboxLeaders API Service is shutting down as of April 31, 2014"

Comment: i have registered my account on xbox one and i'm getting list of games with there scores using xbox one api , but i am unable to found result. is there any other approach (API) to get complete result of a user using there game tag ?